# How to run concurrent operations using asyncio in python?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I want to run "N" concurrent operations in asyncio .
This is the general layout of my code.

```
def heavy_operation(): 
   # Heavy operation 1....N  I want to run concurrently.
for x in range (N) :
  heavy_operation()
```

`heavy_operation` is `GET` request I make to an API. A few lines of string at once. Since N is near 100 my code runs slowly.

Solutions without using for-loop are also fine as long as the heavy operations are running concurrently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your heavy operations are not async (defined with `async def` and actually awaiting IO operations), asyncio won't do you much good because it is single-threaded and suited for parallelizing IO. When parallelizing CPU-bound code, you can use threads directly, like this:

```
import concurrent.futures

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as pool:
    for i in range(N):
        pool.submit(heavy_operation)  # you can also add positional arguments
```

Note that if `heavy_operation` is CPU-bound, it is likely that your code will run no faster than the sequential version due to [the GIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock). In that case you can try changing `ThreadPoolExecutor` to `ProcessPoolExecutor` to run `heavy_operation` in separate python processes.

If `heavy_operation` is IO-bound (e.g. it uses `requests` to download http), the optimal approach would be to convert it to async by switching the underlying library to one that supports asyncio, such as from `requests` to [`aiohttp`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/). Then you'd use `asyncio.gather` to run `heavy_operation` in parallel, as shown [here](https://pawelmhm.github.io/asyncio/python/aiohttp/2016/04/22/asyncio-aiohttp.html) and elsewhere.

Having said that, I'd also add that, in *practice*, spawning 100 threads (assuming you want all your requests to run in parallel) won't encumber a modern system. You'll just need to pass that number to the `ThreadPoolExecutor` constructor, and it will work fine. The benefit of an asyncio is that you get a solution that: a) actually scales, because it will work equally well for 10, 100, or 10,000 concurrent connections, b) avoids many pitfalls with threads, such as race conditions, and c) automatically provides other goodies such as reliable cancellation and timeouts.

Comment: heavy_operation  is  GET request I make to an API. A few lines of string at once. Since N is near 100  my code runs slowly . What do you reccomend? Should I go with async? or should I use your method ?

Comment: I assumed "heavy" meant CPU-bound. If it's in fact http, then async is probably the best way to go, but you will need to switch from `requests` (or whatever you're using now) to `aiohttp`. Then you'll use something like `gather` to parallelize it, as shown [here](https://pawelmhm.github.io/asyncio/python/aiohttp/2016/04/22/asyncio-aiohttp.html) and elsewhere.

Comment: However, in practice, spawning 100 threads is probably not the end of the world (assuming you want all your requests to run in parallel). You'll just need to pass that number to the `ThreadPoolExecutor` constructor. But with asyncio you get a solution that: a) actually scales, because it will work equally well for 10, 100, or 10000 concurrent connections, b) avoids many pitfalls with threads, such as race conditions, and c) automatically provides other goodies such as reliable cancellation and timeouts.

Comment: Thanks this helped ! If you edit the answer with the content of your second comment. I will mark it as correct .

Comment: I have a new problem. The "post" request in my program is made by a wrapper function  so I can't use aiohttp. Is there another way of doing this without aiohttp ?

Comment: @pundit This new problem should be posted as a separate question; this one was explicitly about how to do it in asyncio. Having said that, please note that the very first code example in this answer shows how to do it without aiohttp/asyncio.

Comment: That doesn't work. It takes the same amount of time as a simple for loop.