# How can I run concurrently blocking functions?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm creating a Python app where I receive some data and I need to process this data. I can't do this synchronously, since I'm always receiving data, so I need to process the data concurrently.

The problem is that I'm using a library that doesn't support `asyncio`, so I don't know if I can run it concurrently. Here is my code:

```
async def event_dispatcher(num):
    data = blocking_operation(num)
    print(data)

async def main():
    tasks = [loop.create_task(event_dispatcher(1)), loop.create_task(event_dispatcher(2)), loop.create_task(event_dispatcher(3)),
             loop.create_task(event_dispatcher(4)), loop.create_task(event_dispatcher(5)), loop.create_task(event_dispatcher(6))]
    
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

Where `blocking_operation` is the function that I cannot run concurrently. So basically I expected the function in `tasks` to run at the same time, but because of `blocking_operation`, they will run one at time. Is there any way to solve this? Or am I forced to use another library or multiprocessing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor), which will submit the blocking code in a thread pool behind the scenes:

```
async def event_dispatcher(num):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, blocking_operation, num)
    print(data)
```

Beginning with Python 3.9 you can also use [`asyncio.to_thread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.to_thread):

```
async def event_dispatcher(num):
    data = await asyncio.to_thread(blocking_operation, num)
    print(data)
```

Comment: Wow this is awesome! Thank you a lot! For some reason i was looking into ensure_future to do this. What happens if instead of wrapping the blocking operation in the executore i wrap the entire event_dispatcher?

Comment: @JayK23 You can do that too, but `event_dispatcher` can't be async then. It's best to keep your functions async and only wrap actual blocking calls with `run_in_executor`. That way you can easily add "real" async (such as aiohttp etc) into the mix and get the benefits of asyncio.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I was just concerned that if i have more blocking functions with more run_in_executor the function would become quite messy, but it shouldn't be

Comment: @JayK23 Just be aware that `run_in_executor` is cheating of sorts - it uses threads under the hood and isn't "really" async. It makes sense for incorporating legacy blocking code into your async program, but if you find that your whole asyncio program consists of calls to `run_in_executor`, you might then as well use `concurrent.futures` directly.

Comment: Yeah indeed you are totally right. Luckily it's only that function where i need to run the executors so this solution is perfectly alright. At worst i can use the threading module too only for that function if it's not considered a bad practice

Comment: @user4815162342 Could you elaborate on your alternative way of doing it with concurrent.futures? You could even propose another answer. I'm especially interested to know what is the benefit of doing so as opposed to running multiple `asyncio.to_thread(blocking_func)`. I am well aware that all of this is strongly dependant on what the actual work is.

Comment: @RomainVincent I guess my point was, if the "async" code ends up consisting **only** of `to_thread()` calls, then why bother with asyncio in the first place? It adds substantial complexity over `concurrent.futures`, and still uses them under the hood. If you're curious how to use `concurrent.futures`, you can look at [their documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html), or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62543205/1600898).

Comment: I can answer your question  Although I have quite a bit of experience with Python in general and async programming in Javascript, I am not used to Python futures at all. And oh! are they overwhelming. I can see why people would avoid them. This is made worse by the fact that async seems to have been evolving a lot recently. The documentation is not so clear in my opinion. -- But I agree with you, just by peeking into the definition of to_thread last time I've done async coding, I don't remember the details but I've not used to_thread directly.

Comment: @RomainVincent Well, I don't mean to discourage you from asyncio altogether - you can probably just use async/await and ignore the whole "futures" deal. My point was a very narrow one: if the program is **only** using asyncio to mask legacy blocking calls (which doesn't exist in JavaScript because nothing is blocking there), **then** why bother with it at all. But these days there is ample choice of async-aware libraries, so that situation is no longer a common one.

Comment: @user4815162342 Hmm, I don't think blocking code is necessarily legacy. I have been writing relatively trivial scripts, but without using external libraries, and whenever I had to read from or write to disk, or make http requests, there was no way to do that fully async. That I know of. So I always end up having to wrap blocking code.

Comment: @RomainVincent Writes to disk are in practice often fast enough to not require either async or thread based parallelism, and http requests can be made using libraries like aiohttp that have existed for many years. It is not obvious what is your use case, but I can understand your objections to calling your code "legacy". My recommendation would be to learn more about async in python; perhaps my point will be clearer with more experience. Or maybe it just doesn't apply to what you're doing. In either case, have fun with python async!

Comment: @user4815162342 thanks. No worries I didn't take the legacy part for me.  -- I've already used httpx quite a bit. But there are some use-cases where I prefer a single portable script without having to deal with dependencies. Just need a bit more practice.